# Select subsets of data based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` in the following structure:
`df`:

```
   12     14   15   16    18   29    31   32   33    36    46    48   49   50   52
0  0   1950  136  -25  -116    1  1664  372  -17   NaN     1  2950  449  -24  NaN
1  0   1635  373  -21  -115    0  1639  261  -24  -116     1  2950  160  -24  NaN
1  0   1635  373  -21  -115    1  1639  261  -24   NaN     1  2950  160  -24 -111
```

in the columns `12`, `29`, and `46` I have indicators `0` or `1`
I named this list of indices by : 
`col = [12,29,46]`
My aim is to find the correct syntax in `Python` to code this:

```
for i in col: 
    check df[i] 
    while df[i] == 0 and df [i+6] is not NaN:
        select df[i+2] , df[i+3] , df[i+4]
    while df[i] == 1 and df [i+6] is not NaN:
        select df[i+2] , df[i+3] , df[i+4]
    if df[i] == 1 and all df[i+6] are NaN:
    Select the first one.
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: another dataframe with the selected columns values from the code above.

Comment: Then just use this : `df = df[col]`

Comment: but there are some conditions to select the columns as mentionned

Comment: It would help if you [edit] the question to include your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing too much about the details of Panda dataframes, I'd say you need to take this problem generally. If you want to create your own implementation, you should create a filter function, to which you pass two arguments: your dataframe and a **predicate function** (a function that you should write, which will returns True or False on a row of dataframe).

Something like:

```
def my_test_function(row):
    ....
    # result must be boolean (or something equivalent)
    return result

def filter_dataframe(df, predicate):
   return [row for row in df.rows if predicate(row)]

rows = filter_dataframe(df, my_test_function)
```

Hence you must write `my_test_function` according to your needs.

Note also, that Panda provides a whole set of facilities for filtering ([see in particular this page](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/filter_dataframes/)). But if it doesn't fit your needs, the pattern above could be an elegant solution.